# Spy on Date.now() results in jasmine-node not responding

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, jasmine-node

I am using jasmine-node for doing unit testing. I did below code for mocking Date.now()

```
spyOn(Date, 'now').andReturn(1387636363717); //always return a fixed time
```

Then I tried to run `jasmine-node spec/` but it stopped working with no output. I could not figure out what is the reason.

Answer (score 6):

I have written a tiny test. It works just fine. Using jasmin-node in version 1.11.0.

Where is your Date.now function used then?

```
spyOn(Date, 'now').andReturn(1387636363717);
expect(Date.now()).toEqual(1387636363717);
```

Comment: my code is exactly the same as your code. my jasmine-node version is 1.12.0

Comment: I also tried jasmine-node 1.11.0, the same issue. OS is Ubuntu 12. Don't know why spying on Date.now results in jasmine-node not working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is code in node runtime (`timers.js`) that calls `Date.now()` to mark the passage of time. If you have code that sets a timer (`setTimeout`) and that code is executed while not using `jasmine.Clock`, then you may find node.js is waiting for some time to pass before executing the next *real* timeout. Since this code appears to be called from outside javascript land, you can not rely 
on the single-threaded nature of javascript to keep you safe from this. By putting a breakpoint on a `.andCallFake` on the `Date.now` spy, I was able to see that the execution of the spec was being indefinitely suspended waiting for a millisecond to pass.

This is a problem for me because we have a very large unit test suite and there are possibilities that `setTimeout` is called as a side effect of some other calls and `jasmine.Clock` is not used universally in every spec. Since this is the side effect of an optimization (note: 'too much overhead' in the comments), I would consider this to be a bug in node.js.

If you want to stop time for your tests:

1. Spy on Date.now inside your spec function (`it` function - not `beforeEach`). That way your spec won't be delayed (also explains why @marco.jantke did not see this issue).
2. if your code under test uses timers, use `jasmine.Clock`.